# Convention for stacking k matrices together, is result k-by-..-by.. or ..-by-..-by-k?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, eigen

If I have an k mxn matrices, and I stack them together, should the result kxmxn or mxnxk? In numpy it's the former, is this a common convention?

IE,

```
numpy.array([matrix1, matrix2, matrix3])
```

will give (3,x,x) array

Comment: The `numpy.linalg` gufuncs take `k` stacked inputs as `(k, ..., ...)`, see e.g. [`np.linalg.inv`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html), which is probaby the closest to a convention that it is going to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.array` isn't a 'stacking' function.  What you demonstrate is a particular consequence of how it operates.  `numpy` also has `concatentate` and its special cases `hstack`, `vstack`, and `dstack`.  2 of those don't add a dimension, and the 3rd adds it at the end.

`np.array` behaves like `np.concatenate([matrix1[None,...], matrix2[None,...]])`.  This is, I think, a consequence of a broader tendency to pre-pend dimensions as needed, for example in

```
np.array(matrix1, ndim=3)  # (1,x,x) shape
```

In MATLAB/Octave,

```
[matrix1, matrix2, matrix3]  # like np.hstack
cat(2, matrix1, matrix2, matrix3]   # also horzcat
[matrix1;matrix2]  # np.vstack
cat(1, matrix1 ...)  # also vertcat
cat(3, matrix1 ...)  # like np.dstack
```

Adding a dimension at the end comes natural to Octave.  Adding a dimension at the start is more awkward in Octave.  Best I can think of, off hand, is

```
[reshape(matrix1,1,x,x); reshape(matrix2,1,x,x)]
```

Comment: Thanks for examples. Another place where numpy prepends dimensions is when broadcasting. IE, np.ones((3))+np.ones((2,3)) works, but np.ones((2))+np.ones((2,3)) fails. Couldn't find any other systems that prefer this "prepend on the left" convention, wonder where it came from.

Comment: pre-pend is more natural with `C` ordering, post-pend with `F` ordering.  MATLAB/Octave started as a wrapper for FORTRAN functions.  `numpy` has had broadcasting for a long time.  Octave (and Matlab?) added it more recently.  Initially it was limited to 2d (back in Matlab 3.5 days), while `numpy` has been multi-dimensional all along.  `APL` is an even older array language, but I don't recall how it handled this 'stacking'.